# Android Testing: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description;

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-testing

I encounter the following runtime errors when doing the instrumentation test.

```
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description;
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I think there are many similar questions with this issue.

However, most of them suggest to exclude the hamcrest librarty from other dependencies, but it did not solve my problem :(

Here is the dependencies part of my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile files('libs/java-hamcrest-2.0.0.0.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/hamcrest-json-0.2.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/jsonassert-1.2.3.jar')
    androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.3')
    {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude module: 'objenesis'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.3') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude module: 'objenesis'
    }

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }

}
```

I use `gradle dependencies`  and  there is no `hamcrest-core` in `androidTestCompile`, but still fails at the instrumentation time.

Something important I miss?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception

Comment: I add a  `configurations { all *.exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'}` and it still does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Gradle DexException - Multiple dex files defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702267/android-gradle-dexexception-multiple-dex-files-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After deeply look into the result of `gradle dependencies`, I found that the root cause is that `org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito` contains `mockito-all` module.

However, the `mockito-all` module contains `hamcrest` library internally ( but you can not see it with `gradle dependencies`), which is conflicted with the other dependencies.

So, to fix this, we need to replace `org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito` with `org.powermock:powermock-api-support`, which does not contain `mockito-all`.

Replace

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile ('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.3') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude module: 'objenesis'
    }
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-support:1.6.3'
}
```

should work for me.