# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description;

Tags: java, android, junit

I've  searched Stackoverflow for this error and found a lot of solutions and tried them all, none worked for me, for example changing `junit` to "4.8+" or adding these to `build.gradle` file:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
}


androidTestCompile ('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.+'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.+'
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-support:1.6.3'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
```

I'm always getting this error :

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define    Lorg/hamcrest/Description;

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

When changing `junit` to "4.8+" it says there's a conflict, and I need to make it 4.11.

What's the solution!

Comment: Try changing the hamcrest-library to the one that is likely being included by one of the other packages. In my case I was able to fix the problem by switching to androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3' you can find out which libraries and versions are being included by opening the terminal and running gradlew app:dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Gradle DexException - Multiple dex files defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702267/android-gradle-dexexception-multiple-dex-files-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by replacing it by :

```
androidTestCompile('junit:junit-dep:4.8.+')
```