# Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description (w/o JUnit)

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.1

The error I get when trying to compile my app in Android Studio is:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description;
```

I have searched on this site and every result with this error had a solution involving changing a JUnit dependency. I do not explicitly use this. These are my only dependencies:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

Can you tell me what the conflict is here and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Related: [Android Gradle DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702267/android-gradle-dexexception-multiple-dex-files-defined)